# Gimp: How to create a selection from file in Python

Tags: gimp, layers, mask, selections, python

I am using Gimp's non-interactive mode, since I want to process a big number of images and their masks. For every image file, I have a mask image file, which consists of 1 and 0s (1 means the pixel should be selected). How do I select those in Python? I am looking at the reference [here](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/pdb/index.html). What I see is that there is a function called `gimp_selection_load`, which loads the selection from a channel. However, I don't know how to convert the mask image to a channel. I tried reading it with `gimp_file_load` and then `gimp_image_get_channels`, but there are no channels found in the mask image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to load your mask as a new layer, do a color selection from it, and then remove it. So assuming that `image` is your current image:

```
import gimpcolor

# load mask as layer
mask=pdb.gimp_file_load_layer(image,'/path/to/mask.png')
pdb.gimp_image_add_layer(image, mask,0)

# get selection
pdb.gimp_image_select_color(image, CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE, mask,gimpcolor.RGB(0,0,0))

# drop the mask layer
pdb.gimp_image_remove_layer(image,mask)
```

Comment: "copy the layer to a channel in the initial image" how do I do that? Which function should I use?

Comment: The channel copy is more complicated that it seems. See edited answer for a a simpler solution. If you do batch scripts, some hints and sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).

Comment: Fantastic. I have been fighting with this for quite some time, and turned out that my main mistake was forgetting to remove the layer! It's great that you included a snippet.